# setting identity specification on in c# code

Tags: c#, identity

I am trying to write a c# method to set on the identity specification. But it is not working. This is my code:

```
        string sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + table + " ON";
        string sql2 = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + table + " OFF";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn);

        conn.Open();

        if (identity == true)
        {
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        else
        {
            cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        }            

        conn.Close();
    }
```

The terms "table" and "identity" are parameters.

Am I doing anything wrong? Could you help me, please?

Thank you, very much!

Comment: Did you try `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: Your code is subject to SQL injection. Use parameters (or stored procedures).

Comment: Advice: never say, "It is not working". Instead, tell us what you thought should happen, and show us what actually happened.

Comment: @AndrewSpencer thank you for the advice! It was supposed to set the identity on, but nothing happens. The application runs, but the identity doesn't change from "off" to "on".

Comment: You need to SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON first, then insert all of your data, then run the SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF statement as part of one complete batch. This is better done in a stored procedure, because you can then test it and also everything happens sequentially in one session.

Comment: I was using "DataContextFactory" to manipulate the database. Now, I decided to work only with sql commands. Now it is working. Thank you everyone for the atention.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with your code, but with your logic.  Setting `IDENTITY_INSERT`, along with [lots of other settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx), is done on a per-session basis:

> The Transact-SQL programming language provides several SET statements that **change the current session** handling of specific information.

(emphasis mine)

As soon as your connection is closed, your session is gone, and therefore the setting is also gone.

You'll need to refactor your code to include the setting of `IDENTITY_INSERT` so it is in the same session as the code that makes use of it.

Comment: Let me explain what I am trying to do:

I need to insert datas into a table called "customer". So, listening to your tip, I coded the insert statement bellow the indentity statement (inside the same method), but there is an error telling me that I cannot insert datas since the "identity specification" is set to OFF. What I am not understanding is why the identity continues set to OFF, while I have a statement setting it to ON, in the same method.